How can I differentiate between water body and snow on my Landsat images using ArcGIS?
I am trying to detect changes in water bodies over a couple of decades. but when I use NDWI to calculate water it includes snow in that range as well, I can't differentiate between these two. I even tried a GEE script but the result was no different. I would like to know the process that includes the steps to remove snow from water values provided by NDWI

Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap and what version?

Refer to this research paper https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4441/12/5/1339
